# How to mock a module just to call a function

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Is it possible to make when `someFunction` or any inner function that call `ReactDom.render` use my function instead real implementation?

```js
export const testHelperFunction = (widget, anotherArg) => {
    jest.mock('react-dom', () => {
      return {
      __esModule: true,
      render: console.log,
    }});
    widget.someFunction(anotherArg);
    jest.unmock('react-dom');
};
```

Comment: Is `testHelperFunction` in the same file as your actual test case (e.g.: `it('should pass', () => {...})`)

Comment: @AlanFriedman no, I trying to make it a helper to instead of really render widget when calling someFunction, it would shallow render it. The thing is, someFunction calls another module that calls ReactDom.render. I would like to get what ReadtDom.render would receive and do my things with it, instead of default implementation.

Comment: I see. Could you try moving `jest.mock` to the same file as the test case, and move it outside of that function into the top-level scope of the file?